# How can I split a 56 character input and store them in two Bytes32?

Tags: arrays, bytes, bytes32

I want a function to accept, store and output 56 characters.  My other question ([How to return bytes array in Solidity Contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/how-to-return-bytes-array-in-solidity-contract/24525#24525)) shows that I tried to return bytes[], but it gives me an error:

> Internal type is not allowed for public or external functions

I haven't been able to get past this error.

So now, I would like to see if I can split the 56 character input into two bytes32, so that I can return bytes32.  How do I do this?

I modified the code from this question ([How can I split a Bytes32 source into two halfs and store them in Bytes16?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13143/how-can-i-split-a-bytes32-source-into-two-halfs-and-store-them-in-bytes16)) and created this:

```
  event trace(bytes x, bytes32 a, bytes32 b);

    function foo(bytes source) {
        bytes32[2] memory y = [bytes32(0), 0];
        assembly {
            mstore(y, source)
            mstore(add(y, 32), source)
        }
        trace(source, y[0], y[1]);
    }

  function cut(bytes sha) constant returns (bytes32 half1, bytes32 half2) {
    assembly {
      let freemem_pointer := mload(0x40)
      mstore(add(freemem_pointer,0x00), sha)
      half1 := mload(add(freemem_pointer,0x00))
      half2 := mload(add(freemem_pointer,0x10))
    }
  }
```

But I wasn't able to get them to work.

EDIT on 2017-08-22 for benjaminion:

Ideally, I want to return bytes[].  See my code and the error with bytes[] at [How to return bytes array in Solidity Contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/how-to-return-bytes-array-in-solidity-contract/24525#24525) .  Benjaminion's first block of code worked with a little bit of modification.  I changed my "iterator" function to the following:

```
  function iterator() constant returns (address[],uint256[],uint256[],bytes32[],bytes32[]){
      uint256 len = ledger.keys.length;
      address[] memory keys = new address[](len);
      uint256[] memory values = new uint256[](len);
      uint256[] memory values2 = new uint256[](len);
      bytes32[] memory newKeys1 = new bytes32[](len);
      bytes32[] memory newKeys2 = new bytes32[](len);
      for (uint256 i = 0 ; i <  len ; i++) {
         address key = ledger.keys[i];
         keys[i] = key;
         values[i] = ledger.maps[key];
         values2[i] = token.balanceOf(key);

         bytes memory sha = ledger.newKeys[i];
         bytes32 half1;
         bytes32 half2;

         assembly {
            half1 := mload(add(sha,0x20))
            half2 := mload(add(sha,0x40))
         }
         newKeys1[i] = half1;
         newKeys2[i] = half2;
      }
      return (keys,values,values2,newKeys1,newKeys2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what your question asks about:

```
contract Foo {
  function cut(bytes sha) constant returns (bytes32 half1, bytes32 half2) {
    assembly {
      half1 := mload(add(sha,0x20))
      half2 := mload(add(sha,0x40))
    }
  }
}
```

The point is that the `bytes` quantity `sha` comprises a 32-byte length followed by the actual bytes. So we skip the first 32 (= 0x20) bytes to get `half1`, and then another 32 bytes to get `half2`.

Note that `sha` is a pointer to the start of the data it represents, which is why we can use it like this.

---

Having said this, it's not clear to me why you can't just do the following. `bytes` is a perfectly allowable return type and can have arbitrary length.

```
contract Foo {
  function foo(bytes sha) constant returns (bytes) {
    return sha;
  }
}
```

You probably really want something along these lines.

Comment: Ideally, I want to return bytes[].  See my code and the error with bytes[] at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/how-to-return-bytes-array-in-solidity-contract/24525#24525 .  Your first block of code worked with a little bit of modification.  I added the following to my "iterator" function:
bytes memory sha = ledger.newKeys[i];
         bytes32 half1;
         bytes32 half2;
         
         assembly {
            half1 := mload(add(sha,0x20))
            half2 := mload(add(sha,0x40))
         }
         newKeys1[i] = half1;
         newKeys2[i] = half2;

Comment: Are you willing to review my crowdsale contract before I use it?